# Unable to find src/main/webapp/app/blocks/config/http.config.js or missing required jhipster-needle. Interceptor not added to JHipster app

Tags: jhipster, bootswatch

I just generated a project with jhipster normally. I am now trying to use the Bootswatch theme by typing the command `npm install -g generator-jhipster-bootswatch` and `yo jhipster-bootswatch` as shown on their website and I have this error:

```
Unable to find src/main/webapp/app/blocks/config/http.config.js or missing required jhipster-needle. Interceptor not added to JHipster app.

version :
jhipster 4.13.3
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generator-jhipster-bootswatch is 2 years old , its not compatible with Angular 5 in JHipster 4 (see [issue](https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-bootswatch/issues/10))

Comment: Yes, it's true !! it's a compatibility problem. thank you very much I was able to solve